Correct approach to refactor duplicate API Call to different endpoints
I have two methods that make a call to two different endpoints. The logic is exactly the same, however the API Endpoints have to be kept seperate. How would you refactor this?
    public List<Company> getAllCompanies(String authHeader) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        List<Company> companies = new ArrayList<>();

        long next = 0;

        do {

            CollectionResponse<Company> result = hubspotClient.getCompanies(authHeader, maxBatchSize, next, false, new ArrayList<>());

            next = Optional.ofNullable(result.paging())
                    .map(Paging::next)
                    .map(Next::after)
                    .orElse(0L);

            Envelope<Company> envelope = result.toEnvelope();
            companies.addAll(envelope.items());

            LOG.info("Loaded %d companies (next: %d, overall: %d)".formatted(
                    result.results().size(),
                    next,
                    companies.size()));

        } while (next != 0);

        LOG.info("Loaded %d companies in %ds".formatted(companies.size(), (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000));

        return companies;
    }


    public List<Contact> getAllContacts(String authHeader) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

        long next = 0;

        do {

            CollectionResponse<Contact> result = hubspotClient.getContacts(authHeader, maxBatchSize, next, false, new ArrayList<>());

            next = Optional.ofNullable(result.paging())
                    .map(Paging::next)
                    .map(Next::after)
                    .orElse(0L);

            Envelope<Contact> envelope = result.toEnvelope();
            contacts.addAll(envelope.items());

            LOG.info("Loaded %d contacts (next: %d, overall: %d)".formatted(
                    result.results().size(),
                    next,
                    contacts.size()));

        } while (next != 0);

        LOG.info("Loaded %d contacts in %ds".formatted(contacts.size(), (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000));

        return contacts;
    }

Following that example, there are other methods that call the separate company and contact persitance layers (they have to be kept in different tables).
I tried applying Generic funtions but the mess that resulted from that was uglier than the duplicated code itself. What is the correct way to refactor this code?

Use the template pattern:
Start with a base class:
public abstract class LoaderTemplate<T> {

  public List<T> getAll(String authHeader) {

    List<T> allItems = new ArrayList<>();
    long next = 0;

    do {

      CollectionResponse<T> result = doGetAll(authHeader, next);

      next = Optional.ofNullable(result.paging())
        .map(Paging::next)
        .map(Next::after)
        .orElse(0L);

      Envelope<T> envelope = result.toEnvelope();
      allItems.addAll(envelope.items())

    } while (next != 0);

    return allItems;
  }

  protected abstract CollectionResponse<T> doGetAll(String authHeader, long next);
}

Then just extend for each case, for example:
public class CompanyLoader extends LoaderTemplate<Company> {

  private final long maxBatchSize;

  public CompanyLoader(long maxBatchSize) {

    this.maxBatchSize = maxBatchSize;
  }

  @Override
  protected CollectionResponse<Company> doGetAll(String authHeader, long next) {

    return hubspotClient.getCompanies(authHeader, maxBatchSize, next, false, new ArrayList<>());

  }
}

Since Java got lambdas, it's more common to replace the abstract base class with a concrete class that takes a lambda.
For example, you would inject a BiFunction<String, Long, CollectionResponse<T>>, which would perform the load:
public class LoaderTemplate<T> {

  private final BiFunction<String, Long, CollectionResponse<T>> loader;

  public LoaderTemplate(BiFunction<String, Long, CollectionResponse<T>> loader) {

    this.loader = loader;
  }

  public List<T> getAll(String authHeader) {

    List<T> allItems = new ArrayList<>();
    long next = 0;

    do {

      CollectionResponse<T> result = loader.apply(authHeader, next);

      next = Optional.ofNullable(result.paging())
        .map(Paging::next)
        .map(Next::after)
        .orElse(0L);

      Envelope<T> envelope = result.toEnvelope();
      allItems.addAll(envelope.items())

    } while (next != 0);

    return allItems;
  }
}


This class would then be used as follows:
LoaderTemplate<Company> companyLoader = new LoaderTemplate<>(
  (authHeader, next) -> hubspotClient.getCompanies(
    authHeader, 
    COMPANY_MAX_BATCH_SIZE, 
    next,
    false, 
    new ArrayList<>()
  );
);

